# Email form inside ng switch gives error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an email form within a ng-switch. Whenever I click on send the console gives an error. The error only happens when I add the ng-switch to the form. Not sure why it's an jquery error.

console error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
at Function.n.param (jquery.min.js:4)
at n.$scope.submit (contactController.js:20)
at angular.min.js:199
at f (angular.min.js:216)
at n.$eval (angular.min.js:126)
at n.$apply (angular.min.js:126)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:216)
at HTMLFormElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

contact.html

```
<div class="container" ng-switch on="contactsent">
    <div class="contact col-xs-12" ng-switch-when="default">
        <form ng-submit="submit(contactform, $event)" name="contactform" method="post" action="" role="form">
            form inputs button etc..
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-sent col-xs-12 center" ng-switch-when="success">
        <h2 class="contact-sent-message">You message has been succesfully sent!</h2>
        <a class="contact-sent-back" href="/#/home">Click here to go back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller file

```
MyApp.controller('contactController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.contactsent = 'default';

    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(contactform, e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if (contactform.$valid) {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'contact-form.php',
                data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-success';
                    $scope.contactsent = 'success';

                } else {
                    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                    $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.result='bg-danger';
                }
            });
        } else {
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed <img src="http://www.chaosm.net/blog/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_sad.gif" alt=":(" class="wp-smiley">  Please fill out all the fields.';
            $scope.result='bg-danger';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we see the controller file?

Comment: Just added controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

The problem is with this line, `$scope.formData` is undefined while it must be an object or array

```
  data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
```

Comment: Ah I see. Is there any way to make it work with ng switch?

Comment: Try to put also the form code and will give you the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem was asked and solved before:

[https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+js+"Cannot+read+property+jquery+of+undefined"](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular%20js%20%22Cannot%20read%20property%20jquery%20of%20undefined%22)